# Are the Ubuntu wallpapers open source?

Tags: desktop-background, open-source, svg

I'm looking for the source files (Inkscape SVG, Illustrator or whatever application was used to create them) for the default Ubuntu wallpapers for the last few versions of Ubuntu. Are they available somewhere? If yes, where can I find them?

Comment: I'm not sure what wallpapers you mean exactly, but yes, they are "open source" as in they are released under a license that allows you to modify and distribute them. However, many are just photographs from the community. Also, graphic designers are generally pretty bad at providing "source" for things (I don't think there are Photoshop .psds available, for eaxample).

Comment: @dobey I'm talking about the [default wallpapers](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/09/a-look-back-at-every-ubuntu-default-wallpaper). They are not photographs, they are obviously created with some vector graphics software and I'm looking for the source of those.

Comment: They were probably created with Illustrator or Photoshop, and the "source" svg/psd is probably not available. Graphic designers are very bad at providing such sources.